# Yahoo Rich Text Editor with Asp.net not working

Tags: asp.net, yui, ascx

I have tried to make yahoo rich text editor in my ascx user control but i failed even after taking help from yahoo developers society.

here what i did with it yet.

1) I created ascx user control and paste the text area html code

```
<div class="yuieditor">

<form method="post" action="#" id="form1"> 
    <textarea id="myEditor" name="editor" rows="20" cols="75"> 

    </textarea> 
    </form>
</div>
```

2) I initialized yahoo css and javascript from yahoo  for my rich text editor.

```
<!-- Skin CSS file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.7.0/build/assets/skins/sam/skin.css"/>
<!-- Utility Dependencies -->
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.7.0/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.7.0/build/element/element-min.js"></script>
<!-- Needed for Menus, Buttons and Overlays used in the Toolbar -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.7.0/build/container/container_core-min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.7.0/build/menu/menu-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.7.0/build/button/button-min.js"></script>
<!-- Source file for Rich Text Editor-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.7.0/build/editor/editor-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.7.0/build/connection/connection-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/uploads/2007/10/yui-image-uploader26.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript">
    var myEditor = new YAHOO.widget.Editor('example_editor', {
        height: '300px',
        width: '522px',
        dompath: true,
        animate: true
    });
    yuiImgUploader(myEditor, 'example_editor',
'/wp-content/uploads/2007/12/yui_img_uploader.php', 'image');
    myEditor.render();
</script>
```

but its not working fine :( i am depressed to work with it but i dont want to use any other editor, i only want to use this.

please help.

here is my full code on my ascx.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="yui.ascx.cs" Inherits="YUI.yui" %>

<!-- Skin CSS file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.7.0/build/assets/skins/sam/skin.css"/>
<!-- Utility Dependencies -->
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.7.0/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.7.0/build/element/element-min.js"></script>
<!-- Needed for Menus, Buttons and Overlays used in the Toolbar -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.7.0/build/container/container_core-min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.7.0/build/menu/menu-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.7.0/build/button/button-min.js"></script>
<!-- Source file for Rich Text Editor-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.7.0/build/editor/editor-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.7.0/build/connection/connection-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/uploads/2007/10/yui-image-uploader26.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript">
    var myEditor = new YAHOO.widget.Editor('example_editor', {
        height: '300px',
        width: '522px',
        dompath: true,
        animate: true
    });
    yuiImgUploader(myEditor, 'example_editor',
'/wp-content/uploads/2007/12/yui_img_uploader.php', 'image');
    myEditor.render();
</script>
<div class="yuieditor">

<form method="post" action="#" id="form1"> 
    <textarea id="myEditor" name="editor" rows="20" cols="75"> 

    </textarea> 
    </form>
</div>
```

please help me out why this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using correct control id in your code, Try this:

Change

```
 new YAHOO.widget.Editor('example_editor',
```

to

```
 new YAHOO.widget.Editor('myEditor',
```

Update your code to use correct id - `myEditor` in place of `example_editor` in other part of your code

Also change your code to use `yui-skin-sam` class and not `yuieditor`

Ex:

```
<div class="yui-skin-sam">
```

Working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<!-- Skin CSS file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/assets/skins/sam/skin.css">
<!-- Utility Dependencies -->
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js"></script> 
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/element/element-min.js"></script> 
<!-- Needed for Menus, Buttons and Overlays used in the Toolbar -->
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/container/container_core-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/menu/menu-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/button/button-min.js"></script>
<!-- Source file for Rich Text Editor-->
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/editor/editor-min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript">
    var myEditor = new YAHOO.widget.Editor('myEditor', {
        height: '300px',
        width: '522px',
        dompath: true,
        animate: true
    });

    myEditor.render();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="yui-skin-sam">

<form method="post" action="#" id="form1"> 
    <textarea id="myEditor" name="editor" rows="20" cols="75"> 

    </textarea> 
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You also need to put the script tag after the textarea tag, or use the  onDOMReady event.

Comment: @rs. its working now but i wonder why not to change <div class="yui-skin-sam">  ??? according to my own css class ??

Comment: @rs. may you please help me how to modify yui buttons?
i dont want hyperlink and image uploading button to my yui..how i can remove these?

Comment: @asif, you can use your own css class but your class doesn't include all css required for rendering editor. To remove/add buttons you don't need css, you can specify options to include/exclude buttons, check yahoo docs for info

Comment: @rs. thank you so much...now i will begin my learning with asp.net more easily.

Comment: @rs. i tried to remove buttons of hyperlink and image but could not find better solution yet..if you can help me out with this?

Comment: @asif, check this - http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/editor/toolbar_editor.html

Comment: @rs. thanks for this but how i remove image and hyperlink button..as i tried but image and hyperlink button is not going to remove.how can make css for this.please help

Comment: In above link check options, add everything that is mentioned there after your `animate:true` option, and remove last two buttons that start with `group: 'insertitem', label: 'Insert Item'` to remove image and hyperlink button from your editor.

Comment: @Asif, to do that in CSS, which i think you prefer, do this - `.yui-toolbar-group-insertitem {display:none !important;}`

Comment: @rs. yes i did it on that page but i am confused that how i can make modified css as my link so i could be able to just include css link in my ascx page...

Comment: save that css file from yahoo site in your project with different name and edit it.